# Print/Replace ALT code in Unix

Tags: linux, unix

I am creating a report in pipe separated text file using Application Oracle framework on unix file server. This file is in `iso-8859-1` encoding format. But I need to send to downstream in `UTF-8` format(which I can not generate from Oracle framework) so I am converting it to UTF format using below command:

```
iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t UTF-8//TRANSLIT $i -o $i
```

But there is requirement of replacing `"|"` separator with inverted exclamation mark character `"¡"`

So how can find and replace `"|"` character and replace it with `"¡"` in Unix?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

The INVERTED EXCLAMATION MARK is unicode U+00A1 and is member of the ISO-8859-1 charset with code 0xa1 or 0241 in octal. As you know that your input file is iso-8859-1 encoded, you can convert the pipe with a mere `tr` command:

```
 tr '|' '\241' < infile > outfile
```

You can then use `iconv` to convert outfile from ISO-8859-1 to utf8.

---

Demo (on an ISO-8859-1 terminal):

```
$ echo 'a|b' | tr '|' '\241'
a¡b
$
```

Comment: Thanks for guiding me Serge! But this command did my job -> sed -i 's/|/¡/g' $i